# Div resize according to increase in other div css only

Tags: html, css

I have these two divs. The inner div needs to make the outer div resize as the div fills up with words. Simply the outer div should resize as the content of the inner div increases.

**Note:** The inner div increases height upwards hence the outer div should also increase upwards

Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kevinrobert3/zguo4vbc/51/
as the words in inner div increase and the div increases in height, I need the outer div to match up and increase too

```
<div class="wrapper" id="in">
  <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div">
    it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by 
    the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
  </div>
</div>
```

The css for it is

```
.wrapper{
    width:70%;
    max-height: 500px;
    min-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
    top: 90px;
    height: auto;

}
.wrapper .inner-div  {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0px;
    max-width: 230px;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin-left: 55px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Common behavior is when child content increase parent height automatically increase but if child element has "position:absolute;" in css then it dose not make any impact on parent height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because of your `position: absolute;` in your inner-div. 
Removing it resolves your problem. But maybe you needed it for some other reason ?

Comment: it does indeed fix the problem but it denies the margin properties which he may need for styling

Comment: In the 'Note' I put in the question. the position: absolute, helps me position the inner div to the bottom of the outer div. That is where I need the div to always start then increase upwards

Comment: If it's just for positioning, you can then put a `display:flex; align-items:flex-end;` to your outer div. It will also do the trick ;)
See here : https://jsfiddle.net/vcfx2L6e/

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
```

in `.wrapper` and remove `position: absolute;` in `.inner-div`. Just like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/1zfwso06/